# How do I use with LTSP with a Dell FX170 thin client?

Tags: edubuntu, ltsp

Just got a reconditioned DELL Optiplex FX170 thin client delivered, without an image.

On power-up, I see the message:

DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER

I am very sure all the wires etc are connected properly.

I would like it to PXE boot and find my LTSP installation. I have an HP T5525 with the same connectivity that works fine.

On F12 there's a BIOS boot order menu. The only options available though are LS120, the HDD, CD / DVD [via USB presumably], and various USB options. I do not see 'PXE' or any network card. And I don't know how to change the boot order :(

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the BIOs you usually have to turn on LAN booting.

If that option doesn't exist you could use gpxe on a USB key to PXE boot.

http://etherboot.org/wiki/removable

Comment: Fantastic - thanks. In fact I phoned the supplier: they told me about F2 accessing the BIOS, then it was as you describe & all went smoothly.